Has the countable sum of random variables with gaussian tails again gaussian tails?
my question is if the countable sum of (positive) random variables with gaussian tails has again gaussian tails. More precisely I'm interested if the following sum
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}X_n$ has gaussian tails, where each $X_i$ has gaussian tails.
Thank you!

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

Gaussian Tails is often modeled through the Orlicz-Norm as in https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf Chapter 2.5. As a norm the Orlicz norm fulfills triangular inequality and absolute homogenity. Then it follows directly from these two properties that you sum again has Gaussian tails.

Thank you @crush3dice ! Is this only true if the random variables are independent?

Yeah it does. You will have to require something like $|X_n|_{\psi_2} \le q^n$ though for some $q<2$ to make sure this does not diverge.
I just realized that to show this via triangular inequality you have to handle the limit which might be annoying to do. So you could argue more abstract instead by equipping the probability space where $X_1,X_2,\dots$ stem from with the sub-Gaussian Orlicz norm. Then the sum converges in this norm and by completeness the limit lies in the space of sub-Gaussian variables.
